# unable to drop existing unique key because of foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to generate a Unique key by dropping the existing key on MySQL. My current version is MySQL 5.7

I dropped the existing key using the following query,

```
DROP INDEX `uk_bookid_bookname` ON Books;
```

where BookId is the foreign key.

Then,I added new unique key using the following query,

```
ALTER TABLE Books ADD UNIQUE uk_bookid_bookname (BookId, BookName);
```

I got the following error,

> ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'uk_bookid_bookname': needed in a foreign key constraint

I need to drop the existing key and then add a new unique key. But, it works vice-versa.

Comment: I can't follow: does it work? If it does, then what's the question?

Comment: I need to drop the existing key and then add a new key but it works vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You have to drop the foreign key. Foreign keys in MySQL automatically create an index on the table

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP FOREIGN KEY mytable_ibfk_1 ;
```

then add another index key

Comment: Then, how does it work when I add a unique and then drop the existing one?

Comment: First alter the FOREIGN KEY. add a foreign key constraint to a table using ALTER TABLE, Remember to create the required indexes first,

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html